# jQuery selector does not work on dynamic created content in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have this elements on my site which are added dynamically on jQuery's `document.ready` function.

The problem is that I can't select those element using regular jQuery selectors. The JavaScript runs fine in IE9 and other browsers. I think the reason why it does not work is because the content that I'm trying to alter is added dynamically.

How do I solve this issue?

Code:

```
$('.dynamic').each(function(index)
    {
        $('textarea, input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox], select, input[type=text]', this).each(function()
        {

            var array = $(this).val().split('|||');

            var elements = new Array();

            var target = String('.dynamic_'+$(this).attr('id'));        

            $(target).each(function() //this does nothing in ie7 and 8, seems the target selector is messed up :S
            {
                elements.push($(this)); 
            });

            for (val in array)
            {
                var count = Number(val);    
                $(elements[count]).val(array[val]);         
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: come to think of it are they working on other browsers like firefox or chrome etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't see any specific reason for targeting a javascript to IE7 or
>   IE8 since we are all talking about jQuery here. I believe the real
>   problem is not related to the browser itself, it's the misuse of event
>   bindings.

You have to use the `live()` or `delegate()` method. They both will assign the event to the already existing elements in DOM and to the elements created dynamically.

Ex:

```
$(".element").live("click", function() {  
    //dazzling stuff here
});
```

And with delegate:

```
$('.element').delegate('.context-element', 'click', function() {  
    //dazzling stuff here 
});
```

I suggest you to use `deletage()` instead of `live()` since I already experienced many bugs related to event bubbling in some browsers while using live. Also `delegate()` is much faster too, so if you're working on a very intense application in terms of DOM manipulation, better to use it.

Comment: How do you *select* dynamically added elements in IE7? No mention of event handlers

Comment: I don't see any specific reason for targeting a javascript to IE7 or IE8 since we are all talking about jQuery here. The real problem is not related to the browser, it's the misuse of event bindings. I edited the post to clarify this.

Comment: I'm confused about what events you're referring to? I thought the question was about *selectors* specifically not working in IE7 and IE8. I had a similar issue and lame as it sounds, closing & re-opening IE made the problem go away.

Comment: Oh yes, thats it. Everybody assumed the same thing because problems between browsers and jQuery current selector engine are not common things to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Use `On()` instead of `Live()` if possible.

http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/#.UH24mGmopTg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use live() for elements added at runtime: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select the element after adding them dynamically inside `document.ready` then it should work fine. If you are trying to select element when it doesn't exist and trying to attach event handlers then you should go for `live`.

Comment: well I'm adding inside document ready and it works in all other browsers. It's like ie7 & 8 doesn't modify the com tree or something :S